# RxJS - concat last emitted value with previous values

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

I have a stream of click events - let's call it stream$. In the event handler, I increment a counter (started from 0) and call observer.next passing counter as an argument. When counter is equal to 3 I'm completing the stream.

So let's say that my Observable looks like this:

```
--a---b--c->
```

where a, b and c are click events

Now, I'm taking all previous elements (counter is not equal 3):

```
const a$ = stream$.pipe(filter(x => x !== 3))
```

And the last element (counter is equal 3)

```
const b$ = stream$.pipe(filter(x => x === 3))
```

Okay, so let's concat it - a$ with b$

```
const c$ = a$.pipe(concat(b$))
```

Now, subscribe to `c$`

```
c$.subscribe(console.log)
```

Unfortunately, it won't work. I only get 1, 2 in the console, but not 3 (last one). Can anyone explain to me why this happens?

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-iucduj?file=index.ts

CODE:

```
let clickCounter = 0

const stream$ = Observable.create((observer) => {
  document.addEventListener('click', () => {
    clickCounter++;
    observer.next(clickCounter)

    if (clickCounter === 3) {
      observer.complete()
    }
  })
})

const a$ = stream$.pipe(
  filter(x => x !== 3)
)

const b$ = stream$.pipe(
  filter(x => x === 3)
)

const c$ = a$.pipe(concat(b$))

c$.subscribe(console.log)
```

Comment: can you describe what use case are you actually trying to cover?

Comment: I'm making an http request on every emitted value. Those requests can be retried many times. I want to make sure that last emitted value will be a last request. I know that I can use concatMap and that will do the job, but I want to send requests in parallel, and then at the end send the last request

Comment: [NOT DIRECTLY RELATED TO THE QUESTION] If you are dealing with retrying multiple http requests, you may check this official doc: https://angular.io/guide/practical-observable-usage#exponential-backoff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are two things to be aware of:

1. You're creating two `'click'` event handlers because you make two subscriptions to `$stream`. This means that each click increments `clickCounter` twice which is I think what you don't want.
2. The `concat` operator subscribes to the second Observable `b$` only after `$a` completed. However at the time `$a` completes the value `3` was already emitted to `b$` but nobody was listening.

So I think the best way to achieve what you want to use `share()` for `$stream` and then use `merge` instead of `concat` because `b$` won't emit anything thanks to `filter` anyway.

See your updated demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-t3i7mj?file=index.ts

```
const stream$ = Observable.create(
  (observer) => {
    document.addEventListener('click', () => {
      ...
    })
  })
  .pipe(
    share()
  );

...

const c$ = a$.pipe(merge(b$));
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That is exactly what I wanted to achieve!

Answer (score 1):

In your code, by the time you do the second filter operation, the source will have gotten emptied, and thus b$ will not get anything.

Change your code as follows to make it work as you expect:

```
    const stream2$ = stream$.shareReplay(3);

    const a$ = stream2$.pipe(filter(x => x !== 3));

    const b$ = stream2$.pipe(filter(x => x === 3));

    const c$ = a$.pipe(concat(b$));

    c$.subscribe(console.log);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yes, that worked out, but what to do if I don't know the number I need to pass to shareReplay?

Comment: One solution may be using Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY instead of 3.

Answer (score 0):

Aside the particular use you want to use it for (i'd listen to comments about official http replay patterns), wouldn't you be better off with a bit another approach...something like:

```
var stream$ = Observable.fromEvent(document, 'click').pipe(
  scan((acc:any, val:any) => [...acc,val], []),
  take(3)
);

stream$.subscribe((x) => console.log('emits: ' + x))
```